# how to find the highest value in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a mysql table i.e

```
st_id | name | email | maths | chemistry | bio | social_study
1     | john |@a.com | 20    |  23       | 10  |  15
```

my question is how can i find the highest subject score, the second last and so on  
        Note that all the subject fields have int(11) values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Break your database into 3 tables like:

Students:

```
st_id | name | email  
1     | john |@a.com
```

Courses:

```
cr_id | name  
1     | maths  
2     | chemistry  
3     | bio  
4     | social_studies
```

StudentCourses:

```
st_id | cr_id | score  
1     | 1     | 20   
1     | 2     | 23   
1     | 3     | 10   
1     | 4     | 15
```

Now you can do:

`SELECT s.name, MAX(sc.score) FROM Students s INNER JOIN StudentCourses sc ON s.st_id = sc.st_id;`

Comment: The best answer. Now you can quickly modify courses list without changing your queries. Also, maybe add timestamp field to `StudentCourses` table to allow you select scores by date

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM <table>
ORDER BY <field> DESC
LIMIT <needed number of rows>
```

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM <table>
ORDER BY maths+chemistry+bio+social_study DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly PHP method: I assume you want to maintain association with field names.  In that case, just use [`asort($row);`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) on each row in your query result, assuming you fetched the row as an array.  `asort` will sort the array from lowest value to highest (with additional flags to tweak the results if needed), while maintaining keys.  A `foreach` loop will then allow you to work with each key/value pair in the sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

```
st_id | name | email | maths | chemistry | bio | social_study

1     | john |@a.com | 20    |  23       | 10  |  15
```

The query can be for top marks

```
SELECT id,GREATEST(mark,mark1,mark2) AS `top`  FROM `students`
```