# How to find out the highest total value

Tags: php, mysql

I have following two tables (student and marks):  In `student` table I have information about students and in `marks` table I have information about the marks that the students have got. Now could you please tell me how to find out who got the highest mark calculating the total obtained mark from `marks` table ?

Thanks in Advance :)

p.s. Some may find the question duplicate of this- [how to find the highest value in mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5482067/839685) but in my defense my question is slightly different. :)

Student Table:

```
studentid   student_name
 1001        Jon Bon Jovi
 1002        Charlie Sheen
 1003        Jason Statham
 ... Goes on like this
```

Marks Table:

```
id   studentid totalmark obtainedmark  
1     1001       20          12
2     1002       20          20
3     1003       20          15
4     1001       50          40
5     1002       50          50
6     1003       50          45     
... Goes on like this
```

Comment: Wow… Charlie Sheen is pretty smart.

Comment: @cbuckley Yes He is.. :) He is one of my favorite actors. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return the person with the highest sum of obtained marks:

```
SELECT s.studentid, s.student_name, SUM(m.obtainedmark) as c
FROM students s INNER JOIN marks m ON s.studentid = m.studentid
GROUP BY s.studentid
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Looking at your table though, perhaps it is more useful to return the **highest average test score** returning their average percentage obtained. You can do this using the following I believe:

```
SELECT s.userId, s.name, AVG( ( m.obtainedmark / m.totalmark ) ) as c
FROM bnt_users s INNER JOIN bnt_user_skill_rating m ON s.userId = m.user_id
GROUP BY s.userId
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Thank you very very much GordyD. It is working exactly the way I wanted. :) Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.studentId,s.student_name,sum(m.obtainedmark) as TotalMarks
from Student s
inner join  Marks m
on m.studentid=s.studentid
group by s.studentId,s.student_name
order by TotalMarks desc
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you selected one result from the marks table, ordering it by the obtainedmark field (descending). Then you would have the top mark attained.

```
SELECT * FROM `marks` ORDER BY `obtainedmark` LIMIT 0, 1
```

From here you could then get the student information by using the id from the marks table